# OAuthException/ code = 2500/ message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to get data (like name,gender,birthday, profile picture etc) of the user that is logged in. I have tried following two codes, shown below:

```
 //first: Create request for user's Facebook data
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];

// Send request to Facebook
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    if (!error) {
        // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
        NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
        NSLog(@"%@....",userData);
       _facebookID = userData[@"id"];
        _name = userData[@"name"];
        _location = userData[@"location"][@"name"];
        _gender = userData[@"gender"];
     _birthday = userData[@"birthday"];
        NSLog(@"%@",_name);


        _picutreURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", _facebookID]];

        self.nameField.text=_name;
        self.profilePicture.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_picutreURL]];
        self.profileInfo.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, Live in %@ , Born on %@",_gender,_location,_birthday];



    }
}];
// 2nd:Fetch user data
[FBRequestConnection
 startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                   id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                   NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         NSString *userInfo = @"";

         // Example: typed access (name)
         // - no special permissions required
         userInfo = [userInfo
                     stringByAppendingString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@\n\n",
                      user.name]];

         // Example: typed access, (birthday)
         // - requires user_birthday permission
         userInfo = [userInfo
                     stringByAppendingString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Birthday: %@\n\n",
                      user.birthday]];

         // Example: partially typed access, to location field,
         // name key (location)
         // - requires user_location permission
         userInfo = [userInfo
                     stringByAppendingString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",
                      user.location[@"name"]]];

         // Example: access via key (locale)
         // - no special permissions required
         userInfo = [userInfo
                     stringByAppendingString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Locale: %@\n\n",
                      user[@"locale"]]];

         // Example: access via key for array (languages)
         // - requires user_likes permission
         if (user[@"languages"]) {
             NSArray *languages = user[@"languages"];
             NSMutableArray *languageNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             for (int i = 0; i < [languages count]; i++) {
                 languageNames[i] = languages[i][@"name"];
             }
             userInfo = [userInfo
                         stringByAppendingString:
                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Languages: %@\n\n",
                          languageNames]];
         }

         // Display the user info
         NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
     }
 }];
```

But I get null string in output and detected this error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x9499320 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I had the same problem, and the way I just got it working was to add

```
FBSession.activeSession = fbSession;
```

once the initial handler came back successfully. (`fbSession` is whatever variable you have with the facebook session in it.) I just randomly stumbled upon this (I think from another StackOverflow post). But I don't see it in the docs, and by grepping, it doesn't seem to be in any of the Sample apps. So maybe there's a larger issue with my code that I'm not seeing? I'd be interested to hear how others avoid setting the activeSession, and still are able to run `startForMeWithCompletionHandler`.